# Ubuntu server, restringiendo comandos para user invitado, comando rm no lo tengo permitido pero lo puede hacer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Sigo configurando mi usuario `invitado`, el cual, al entrar por ssh tiene comandos restringidos y un lugar donde no se puede mover **siempre que entre por ssh** .

Los comandos restringidos son estos:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  7 Apr  3 10:40 ls -> /bin/ls
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  3 10:40 mkdir -> /bin/mkdir
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr  4 09:39 touch -> /bin/touch
```

**Aclaracion**: Esos 3 comandos son los unicos que puede usar

Entonces cuando entra el usuario **invitado** y hace por ejemplo : `touch hola.txt` si puede, sin problemas. Pero no quiero que ese fichero que ha creado lo pueda borrar. Si se observa, el comando `rm` no se lo he asignado al usuario. Pero aun así puede borrarlo (su bash entiende el comando `rm`)

No debería de hacerlo no ??

`/etc/passwd` de invitado

```
invitado:x:1001:1001::/home/invitado:/bin/rbash
```

No se que puede ser, si os fijáis le tengo cambiado el `/bin/bash a /bin/rbash`

Comment: ¿Puedes ejecutar `which rm`?

Comment: @PabloLozano Si, le he dado permisos para ese comando (which) y me pone que `rm` tira de `/usr/bin/rm`

Comment: @PabloLozano pero es que es que en el dir `/home/invitado/bin` no le he creado un enlace a `rm`

Comment: Pero claramente puede acceder a /usr/bin